# canvas.getImageData is returning empty array having a canvas filled with canvas.fillText

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I have a canvas, which is filled with the fillText function of canvas..
now i want to get the image data of this canvas.

```
var texttodraw = "hello world";
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '16px serif';
ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"; 
ctx.fillText(txttodraw, 0, 0);
console.log('the text is: ' + txttodraw);
canvas.width = ctx.measureText(txttodraw).width;
canvas.height = 16;
console.log('the image size is: ' + canvas.width + ' x ' + canvas.height);  

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
console.log(imageData);
```

The array  "imageData" conains the height and the width and a array which contains the pixel data which i need. 
But unfortuantely with this code i get a array full of zeros. the console output is:

`ImageData { width: 24, height: 16, data: Uint8ClampedArray[1536] }`

when i click on the data array i see that this is only containing zero values..

'Uint8ClampedArray [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1526 more… ]     '

I have similar code with an canvas which have an image drawed with `canvas.drawImage()` inside, and this is working (the data array contains rgb values of each pixel in the canvas...).

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set **[`textBaseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline)** property to `top` for the context, as the texts are drawn with a baseline set to bottom by default, making the text not visible within the canvas area if its drawn at   `0, 0` position.

You'd also need to set the canvas's `width` and `height` before drawing the text.

---

```js
var texttodraw = "hello world";
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = '20px Verdana';
canvas.width = ctx.measureText(texttodraw).width;
canvas.height = 20;

ctx.font = '20px Verdana';
ctx.textBaseline="top"; 
ctx.fillText(texttodraw, 0, 0);

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// check if image data array contains values other than 0
var data = imageData.data.filter(function(e) {
 return e !== 0;
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Just a note, the default is alphabetic, not bottom.